# Simple rich text or mark up editor library

Tags: library, text-editor, markdown

I am looking for a JS/HTML plugin/library for a rich text/markup editor with a small set of features.

Something like you are using to write your answers here. All the things I have seen so far are really huge and powerful like [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php) or [stackedit](https://stackedit.io/) and it is kind of awkward to use it I only need:

- make text bold
- add a link (nothing fancy here. Only allow user to enter URL)
- add a list
- add a quotation

Does anyone know an RTE which is doing something similar?

It does not matter whether the tool would create a markup or html (I only need it to be understandable for a user to use it). Also I prefer a free-open source tool, I am opened to payed solutions.

P.S. I am looking for a html/js library I can include in my own project, not a desktop program/service I can use to create my texts.

Comment: tinyMCE allows customisation so you can choose which tools to show; does that not suit your needs?

Comment: @congusbongus this is what I am currently using. But as I told, it is awkward to load a heavy tool, knowing that I only need to use few things. A good example can be to always carry with you this [knife](http://ronkimmons.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/wenger-85-swiss-army-knife1.jpg), knowing that all you need is a bottle opener.

Comment: Might sound obvious for you, but could you please edit your question to specify whether you are looking for a widget to embed in a website, or something else? Also, do you want open source? Are you open to non-free solutions? And what syntax should links have? HTML syntax or markdown syntax or wiki syntax?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul thanks for clarifications. I edited the question.

Comment: tinyMCE also allows you to [customise which plugins/themes to include in the js](http://www.tinymce.com/download/custom_package.php). If I choose only the list plugin the library is about 270K minified; this compares to the full library at almost 400K minified (not counting themes). Is this still too big? Is your main concern file size or load time, and what's your criteria for "awkward"?

Comment: @congusbongus I have few concerns there. 270k minified is too much for a thing that in my case should only create link/bold/list/quotation. I am pretty sure there should be a library which will be basic and more lightweight. For example I know that I can use Visual Studio for editing C# files. But if the only thing I need is to add a semicolon in the end, I do not need to use Visual Studio and just ignore all the features that it has. I can open it in notepad.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [comprehensive list of editors](https://github.com/cheeaun/mooeditable/wiki/Alternative-Javascript-WYSIWYG-editors) I have found so far.

And a short list of editors, which I found nice (without all ancient editor, which were not contributed for the last 2 years).

- [medium clone](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor)
- [trix](https://github.com/basecamp/trix)
- [froala](http://editor.froala.com/)
- [bootstrap-wysihtml5](http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/)
- [tinyEditor](https://github.com/jessegreathouse/TinyEditor)
- [jhtmlarea](http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/)
- [wymeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/)
- [summernote](http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/)

Currently I am more inclined towards summernote, [image]

It provides modern-looking UI, kind of small (50Kb), new and currently maintained. Froala is bigger (80Kb), but dual-licensed and also modern and maintainable.

Comment: We are really *not* looking for list type answers - if you are liking one of those try writing up a high quality answer specifically for it. Otherwise I'd suggest making this a comment.

Comment: @NickWilde can you please point me to help-center, where it is written? My question was about possible alternatives, because after more than a week, no one pointed me to any normal alternative, I took a look by myself. When I will investigate further and select the tool I liked, I will update it. P.S. have not seen you complaining about a link and a screenshot from Cornelius.

Comment: oh yeah I didn't notice that there to complain about... I'll go rectify that lack. hmm I can't find where we specifically stated that list answers weren't okay; I thought we'd discussed them but anyways. However if I can't find that we definitely did discuss *link-only* answers (in fact we didn't really have to since they are against the whole SE standards (one of the generic flag reasons). [See this meta topic](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality).

Answer (score 1):

What you need is probably **widgEditor**

> widgEditor is an easily installed, easily customisable WYSIWYG editor for simple content. It replaces existing textareas with an improved editing pane using JavaScript, therefore if you don't have JavaScript (or your browser doesn't support HTML editing) it degrades gracefully.
>
> The widgEditor code is released under a GNU General Public License.

From http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/widgEditor/

[image]

It has only [33.4 kbytes](https://code.google.com/p/widgeditor/downloads/list).

Comment: Thanks for help. But latest update in 2008... Some people do not even remember these ancient days.

Comment: While the screenshot *does* mainly answer the question it is better to include text for those with disabilities so that screen readers and such can help them.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Well yes it is old but unless it is broken old doesn't mean bad - I mean I still play [TES Morrowind](http://store.steampowered.com/app/22320/), despite it being **twelve** years old

Answer (score 0):

Up till now the only thing I have found is the following library [jQuery Notebook](http://raphaelcruzeiro.github.io/jquery-notebook/). It has very limited markup `'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'h1', 'h2', 'ol', 'ul', 'anchor'` which is configurable.

It is really lightweight: only `11Kb` minified and `4kb` gzipped. Still looking for other alternatives.

After additional days of search I found another thing: [scribe](https://github.com/guardian/scribe). The problem is that it has not been tested in a lot of devices.