# Windows plain text editor that allows to bold/italicize/indent

Tags: windows, gratis, text-editor, text-processing, plain-text

I write quite a bit in plain text files.  A simple text editor, like Notepad, meets most of my needs when writing plain text files.

But sometimes being able to **bold** or *italicize* a word is very useful.  And being able to indent a section of text is a big plus.  Outside of that, I don't need much for these documents (see [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13553/lean-and-fast-rtf-rich-text-file-editor-with-more-features) for when more is needed).  A spelling checker is a plus, but definitely not essential.

There are tons of great notepad and word processor programs out there, but most are overkill for this simple purpose.  Really, all I need is **bold**, *italicize*, and indent.

I would like to save the file as a plain text file (with appropriate markup or Markdown, which will be needed), or if I absolutely have to, as an RTF (Rich Text File).

I want the program to be Windows 7 compatible, fast, lean, free, and preferably portable.

*(I've tried [Jarte](http://www.jarte.com/) Portable, but it only handles RTF or completely non-formatted text (no markup), and there is something about it that after it starts, the cursor spins like it is busy for 2-4 seconds, which I know is a bit picky, but I find momentarily interrupts workflow.)*

Comment: AFAIK you can't have bold, or italicised text I'm a *plain text* file, because it doesn't support it - you can only have normal text characters. Which means you'll have to save in RTF...

Comment: @ṧнʊß You are absolutely correct.  The text editor needs to interpret the plain text to provide the additional functionality.  That's how markup, markdown, and RTF all work.  They store the file as plain text, but interpret certain sequences of plain text to apply formatting.  The indent function can actually be performed in a rudimentary way without any markup, but to get it to really work, you need the editor to perform some sort of interpretation such as that offered by markup, markdown, or RTF.

Comment: @ṧнʊß Reading your comment again, I realize that I need to clarify a little.  I'll do that now.  Thank you!

Comment: So you want to create a file that can only be read *properly* (with the markup) on that program?

Comment: @ṧнʊß Both created and read.  Basically, a little more functionality than notepad, and much less functionality than wordpad.

Comment: You most likely will wish to take a look at **Markdown**, which basically is "plain-text with formatting". See e.g. [Markdown editor with structure view](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10215/185) / [Simple Rich text or mark up editor](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3248/185) / [Markdown editor for Windows with inbuilt live viewer inside the editor itself](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/5746/185) / [more](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=Markdown+answers%3A1)

Comment: PS: To get an idea what Markdown is, click on this link: [edit] #D

Comment: @Izzy Markdown considers indentation as the beggining of a ``code block``, so I'm not sure it's something the OP wants

Comment: Does it? I use "[fenced code blocks](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/fenced_code_blocks.html)" for that, supported by many Markdown dialects (e.g. [GitHub Flavored Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/), [Markdown-Extra](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/), and others).

Comment: How should indentation work? Any graphical effect (e.g., different background color or a left border)? Different levels of indentation? Or asked differently: Would using the Tab key not be sufficient? (if not, why?)

Comment: I need indent to work so that when word wrap is enabled the wrapped lines are indented as well.

Comment: How about html as it is basically a text file?  <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i> You could use seamonkey or other html editor.

Comment: @cybernard In many ways an HTML editor would be excellent because the markup is so simple.  But I've never seen a WYSIWYG HTML editor that is fast and lean.  Do you know of one?

Comment: How lean?  In today's world 30mb is not outrageous.  http://www.seamonkey-project.org/

Comment: @cybernard Honestly, for this function, I would consider under 1 MB to be lean.  But up to 5 MB (uncompressed) might be fine.  Of course, a very talented programmer could make it under 200KB.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/kompozer/   This is as close as I have come so far.

Comment: Have you tried wordpad? It comes preinstalled on most Windows installations.

Comment: why not using wordpad?

Answer (score 2):

If you need formatting only during first openin, not needed saving of formatting, then try **[SynWrite](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/download.html)**:

[image: sample]

- you need Beta version (link at site)
- you need to install "Color Text" via "Options - Addons manager - Install"
- then you need to configure "Color Text" via ini file, it's simple, if you can't, ask at SW forum, just n lines in ini file